# Assign an external function as staticmethod in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a module, that contains a bunch of functions that generate xml's

In other module I am constructing a class, and I want to assign one of those function to a class variable

Problem is, the fuction acts as a class method and when i call it from another class method, it passes self as a first argument.

Did i choose a good design approach? How to avoid passing self to a function? (@staticmethod decorator before generate = gen.generate doesn't work)

I would like to avoid making a class out of generate function  if possible

Thanks!

generators.py

```
def generate(id, date):
    pass

def generate_another():
    pass
```

main.py

```
import generators as gen

class Client():
    generate = gen.generate

    def get_result(self, *args, **qwargs):
        request = self.generate(id, date)
```

Comment: Why do you even need to `self.generate`? Why not just call it directly as `gen.generate()`. Why should it be a static method instead of a function? This smells strongly of http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @jordanm - a subclass can define a different `generate` or even an object method `generate` that uses state on the object and `get_result` would still work. Not saying that's the intent here, but its a reasonable pattern.

Comment: @tdelaney personally, if that's the case, I would prefer to provide that externally as an argument, so `client = Client(gen.generate)`. Then there's not even a need for the staticmethod decorator

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - yes, that is a good way to go. But I've written factory functions that do something kind-of like this using external configuration. In my case, it was a test suite and the goal was to keep the test cases as generic as possible.

Comment: @tdelaney yeah, my intent was for subclassing, creating different clients with different generators (and other behaviour) and sharing get_result method. How did you archeve it? Similar to juanpa.arrivillaga's answer?

Comment: Yes. You can use `staticmethod()` or `classmethod()` or even `types.MethodType()` for an instance method. These wrap a function in the objects python uses for static, class and member functions.

Answer (score 2):

You must understand, that:

```
@decorator
def some_func():
    pass
```

Is just syntactic sugar for

```
def some_func():
    pass

some_func = decorator(some_func)
```

So in this case, you just want:

```
import generators as gen

class Client:
    generate = staticmethod(gen.generate)

    def get_result(self, *args, **qwargs):
        request = self.generate(id, date)
```

As to whether or not this is a good design decision, it's probably too much of an opion-based question. Personally, I tend to avoid `staticmethod`. What advantage does this design offer over simply calling `gen.generate` inside `get_result`?

Comment: The intent was creating a bunch of clients with different generators. So to every subclass i wanted to assign it's own generator function in a uniform way. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is nearly a duplicate of @juanpa.arrivillaga's answer, but with a simplification which highlights a potential design advantage, addressing Juanpa's question in the case where we're truly using a static method (no `self` arg needed).

Code which originally looks like this (class with a decorated static method)...

```
import generators as gen

class Client:

    @staticmethod
    def get_result(*args, **qwargs):
        request = gen.generate(id, date)
```

... could be simplified as:

```
import generators as gen

class Client:
    get_result = staticmethod(gen.generate)
```

In Juanpa's answer, the class has two ways of calling the same underlying `gen.generate`:

```
client = Client()

# 1. as a class method
client.get_result()

# 2. as a static method
client.generate()
```

This all neglects the details of what is done with the `request` object etc, but if the same external function can be recycled completely as a staticmethod in multiple classes, Juanpa's answer helps keep static methods DRY:

```
def recycled_function(some_arg):
    ...


class ClassOne:
   static_func = staticfunction(recycled_function)


class ClassTwo:
    static_func = staticfunction(recycled_function)
```

This approach is more concise than copying the full implementation of `recycled_function` into each class decorated by `@staticmethod`, or even by making a wrapper method or static function to call the external `recycled_function`.